# How do I fix the CA2202 warning?

Tags: c#

Below is a method that I use to parse an XML. It is giving the CA2202 warning on code analysis which says that the object mStream can be disposed multiple times and I should not call dispose more than once. How can I solve this warning?

```
public static String PrintXML(String XML)
    {
        String result = "";
        string[] xmlSeperators = new string[] { "<?" };
        string[] splitResults = new string[2];

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(XML))
        {
            using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(mStream, Encoding.Unicode))
                {
                    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
                    try
                    {
                        // Load the XmlDocument with the XML.
                        //Check if it is only XML 
                        if (XML.StartsWith("<?"))
                        {
                            document.LoadXml(XML);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Split the string appended before XML
                            splitResults = XML.Split(xmlSeperators, 2, StringSplitOptions.None);
                            if (splitResults.Length > 1)
                            {
                                string d = "<?" + splitResults[1];
                                document.LoadXml(d);
                            }
                        }
                        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                        // Write the XML into a formatting XmlTextWriter
                        document.WriteContentTo(writer);
                        //xx.WriteTo(writer);
                        writer.Flush();
                        mStream.Flush();
                        // Have to rewind the MemoryStream in order to read its contents.
                        mStream.Position = 0;
                        // Read MemoryStream contents into a StreamReader.
                        StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(mStream);
                        // Extract the text from the StreamReader.
                        String FormattedXML = sReader.ReadToEnd();

                        if (splitResults[0] != null)
                        {
                            result = splitResults[0] + "\n" + FormattedXML;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result = FormattedXML;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (XmlException xe)
                    {
                        Log.Error(xe);
                        throw;
                    }                        
                }                   
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately XmlTextWriter did not get the same overload as StreamWriter in .NET 4.5 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712853(v=vs.110).aspx) so you'll have to do what Habib said.  Usually I do things like `new XmlTextWriter(new MemoryStream(), ...` to make it clear that XmlTextWriter owns the stream--but really doesn't fit in your example because you're using the stream after XmlTextWriter is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for getting this warning is that `XmlTextWriter.Dispose()` will ensure that the under lying `MemoryStream` object is also disposed. So when the `using` scope of the `MemoryStream` ends, it will try disposing the `MemoryStream` object and hence the warning.

`using` block compiles into a `try-finally` block. Inner `using` block in your code would call `Dispose` on your `writer`. That will call `Dispose` on your `MemoryStream` object `mStream`. At the exit of control from inner using block, the outer using block will try to dispose the object `writer`, but since it has already been disposed, you are getting the warning on Code analysis tool.

To get rid of the warning, you can remove the first `using` statement and use a `try-finally` block. **But remember to set `mStream` to `null`** as soon as you enter the second `using` statement. This has been explained at [CA2202: Do not dispose objects multiple times](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx)

Your code would look like:

```
public static String PrintXML(String XML)
{
    String result = "";
    string[] xmlSeperators = new string[] { "<?" };
    string[] splitResults = new string[2];

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(XML))
    {
        MemoryStream mStream  = null;
        try
        {
            mStream = new MemoryStream();
            using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(mStream, Encoding.Unicode))
            {
                mStream = null; // important 
                XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
                try
                {
                    // Load the XmlDocument with the XML.
                    //Check if it is only XML 
                    if (XML.StartsWith("<?"))
                    {
                        document.LoadXml(XML);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Split the string appended before XML
                        splitResults = XML.Split(xmlSeperators, 2, StringSplitOptions.None);
                        if (splitResults.Length > 1)
                        {
                            string d = "<?" + splitResults[1];
                            document.LoadXml(d);
                        }
                    }
                    writer.Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented;
                    // Write the XML into a formatting XmlTextWriter
                    document.WriteContentTo(writer);
                    //xx.WriteTo(writer);
                    writer.Flush();
                    mStream.Flush();
                    // Have to rewind the MemoryStream in order to read its contents.
                    mStream.Position = 0;
                    // Read MemoryStream contents into a StreamReader.
                    StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(mStream);
                    // Extract the text from the StreamReader.
                    String FormattedXML = sReader.ReadToEnd();

                    if (splitResults[0] != null)
                    {
                        result = splitResults[0] + "\n" + FormattedXML;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = FormattedXML;
                    }
                }
                catch (XmlException xe)
                {
                    Log.Error(xe);
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        finally 
        {

            if (mStream != null)
            {
                mStream.Dispose();
            }

        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the indepth explaination :)

Answer (score 1):

You can Suppress the error warning as the other answer is saying, but the actuall way to remove this problem to actually calling the `.Dispose()` method only once in your code and only after you're done working with it. A disposed object would raise, System.ObjectDisposedException exception if you dispose it again, but is not for sure. A correct dispose method can be called on an object, multiple times and will/might not generate an error for you. But is not guaranteed to do so.

The fix for this has been stated by Microsoft's Developer Network document,

> To fix a violation of this rule, change the implementation so that regardless of the code path, Dispose is called only one time for the object.

For more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have nested `using` statements where the inner statement contains the resource from the outer statement. In this case, the `XmlTextWriter` will dispose of the `MemoryStream` when it is disposed, and then the outer `using` statement will cause it to be disposed for a second time.

You can manually dispose the MemoryStream by replacing the outer `using` statement with a try/finally:

```
MemoryStream mStream = null;
try
{
    mStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(mStream, Encoding.Unicode))
    {
      mStream = null;
     ...
    }
}
finally
{
    if(mStream != null)
        mStream.Dispose();
}
```

(See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx)